# Building a parabolic roof with stock lumber

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Hope I can describe this without screwing up!

1" x 4" lumber can be bought in 16 foot lengths.  If you choose your wood carefully, you can bend it into arches.

I want to make an arch roof for a playhouse I'm building for my grandkids.  I'm assuming that when the 1 x 4 is bent to form a roof that the resulting shape is a parabola (quadratic).

I live in an area that can get quite a snow load, so the higher the arch, the better the snow will slide off.  So my problem is how wide a length can the roof span and still have sufficient height to facilitate the snow sliding off when using a 16' board?

More specifically, how can I find an equation for the parabola, knowing two points on the curve (but not the vertex) with an arc length of 16 feet?

I realize I could just skip all the math and play with a 16 board, but this question is consuming me intellectually.

Comment: This would be a fine question on MathStackExchange... can a moderator move it?

Comment: It seems to be not so easy: according to the formula at https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/vCalc/Parabola+-+arc+length, length of a parabolic arc with base $b$ and height $a$ is given by$$L=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{16 a^2+b^2}+\frac{b^2}{8 a}\log \left(\frac{4a+\sqrt{16 a^2+b^2}}{b}\right).$$I don't think it is possible to solve for either $a$ or $b$ in closed form.

Comment: The shape looks like a parabola, but I don't think it is, exactly.  For one thing, if you push hard enough and the strips are flexible enough, it will close up.